# Is it OK to use Cassandra Collections?

Tags: database, cassandra, cql, nosql

I have read a lot of blogs telling not to use Cassandra COLLECTIONS. Since UPDATE operation also creates Tombstone, it will affect performance. And it can cause death of application due to excess tombstones.

Is it ok to store less updated data like secondary mobile numbers, email of a user ?
etc ?

OR Should I avoid collections by using CSV or JSON storing in Varchar ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, you can use collection**

Remember there is a size limitation on collection :

- Collection (List): collection size: 2B (2^31); values size: 65535 (2^16-1) (Apache Cassandra™ 2.1 and later, using native protocol v3)
- Collection (Set): collection size: 2B (2^31); values size: 65535 (2^16-1) (Apache Cassandra 2.1 and later, using native protocol v3)
- Collection (Map): collection size: 2B (2^31); number of keys: 65535 (2^16-1); values size: 65535 (2^16-1) (Apache Cassandra 2.1 and later, using native protocol v3)

And For tombstone creation test, Let's say you have the table

```
CREATE TABLE playlists (
    id uuid,
    song_order int,
    tags set<text>,
    PRIMARY KEY(id, song_order )
);
```

If you use the below update statement, tombstone will be created

```
UPDATE playlists SET tags = {'1973'}
    WHERE id = 62c36092-82a1-3a00-93d1-46196ee77204 AND song_order = 1;
```

But if you use the below update statement, will not create tombstone

```
UPDATE playlists SET tags = tags + {'1973'}
    WHERE id = 62c36092-82a1-3a00-93d1-46196ee77204 AND song_order = 1;
```